# 8086 - Beep until get input

Tags: assembly, emu8086, beep

I am new to assembly language and i want to create a program with 8086 assembly. (emu8086) So the program is supposed to continuously beep until key E is pressed. now the first way is to use a simple jump to check input each time and this is the code that i came up with :

```
    macro beep
    mov dl,7h
    mov ah,2
    int 21h
endm

.model small
.stack 64

.code :  

lp:

beep

mov ah,1
int 21h

cmp al,'e'
je end

jmp lp

end:
mov ah,4ch
int 21h
```

Now what i want to achieve is that beeping must be continuous and i dont want the user to do input in each cycle. Something like multi threading in C which beeping is done in another thread.

is that even possible in 8086 ?

Comment: You can try [BIOS `16h` services](http://www.stanislavs.org/helppc/int_16.html) instead of DOS `21h` to have more options how to check keyboard (but it's still buffered read with repeat configuration of typing keyboard, if you would want action-game-like keyboard in DOS, you would have to install your own keyboard handler interrupt code, which would process interrupt requests directly from keyboard). I'm not sure how much continuous the beep will be, even if you call it continuously, that DOS service is not exactly a music API.

Comment: "is that even possible": 'beeping' is constantly turning on/off the buzzer in a given frequency. At e.g. 10k hertz, you have 100ms time to find out, if the key is pressed or not, this should be enough time. so yes - it should be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BIOS function 01h checks if a key is pending.

- If not, you immediately re-beep.
- If a key is present, you fetch it with BIOS function 00h, and if it's not 'e', you continue to re-beep.

This is probably the simplest solution to get a continuous beep until the character 'e' is pressed.

```
lp:
 beep
 mov ah, 01h
 int 16h      ;Gives ZF
 jz  lp       ;No key waiting
 mov ah, 00h
 int 16h      ;Gives AX
 cmp al, 'e'
 jne lp
 mov ax, 4C00h
 int 21h
```

Answer (score 0):

If it emulates the standard PC environment, you can setup the timer "chip" (8255 in hardware) to control the speaker.  Turn that on and it beeps until you turn it off no matter what else your code is doing.